# Limit amount of writes to database using memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to modify the guestbook example webapp to reduce the amount of database writes.

What I am trying to achieve is to load all the guestbook entries into memcache which I have done.

However I want to be able to directly update the memcache with new guestbook entries and then write all changes to the database as a batch put.() every 30 seconds.

Has anyone got an example of how I could achieve the above? it would really help me!

Thanks :)

Comment: You're the second person asking about something like this recently. I think there are some bad optimization lessons going around. You should avoid doing individual puts, and attempt to batch puts whenever possible, but you should never put data you want to see again into memcache without writing it to the datastore first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a recipe for lost data. I have a hard time believing that a guest book is causing enough write activity to be an issue. Also, the bookkeeping involved in this would be tricky, since memcache isn't searchable.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve is called [Write-Behind Caching](http://wiki.tangosol.com/display/COH32UG/Read-Through,+Write-Through,+Refresh-Ahead+and+Write-Behind+Caching#Read-Through%2CWrite-Through%2CRefresh-AheadandWrite-BehindCaching-WriteBehindCaching), and usually it's not so easy to implement the right way as it seems at first. As I know for now there is no ready solutions in Python for Memcached/GAE, but you can look at [Stockpyle](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stockpyle/). It has some basic functionality for [Write-Through Caching](http://wiki.tangosol.com/display/COH32UG/Read-Through,+Write-Through,+Refresh-Ahead+and+Write-Behind+Caching#Read-Through%2CWrite-Through%2CRefresh-AheadandWrite-BehindCaching-WriteBehindCaching) (see appengine.py and memcache.py), so it can serve you as a basis for your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache is such a volatile storage to store valuable data like guestbook entries; remember that memcache data could be evicted in case of low memory for example.

If your guestbook has an high traffic and you are suffering write datastore timeouts/contention, try with another approach using a rate limited [taskqueue](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html) to slow down the number of writes to datastore.

1. Let the user compile the guestbook entries
2. Pass each data entry to a rate limited taskqueue via [deferred](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/deferred.html) library
3. Write to datastore

You can relax the write to datastore defining a low rate execution in your `queue.yaml` with something like this:

```
queue:
- name: relaxed-write
  rate: 1/s
  bucket_size: 1
```

With one write per second, you would probably get some sporadic timeout errors; in this case the task will be executed again until it succeeds.